# Travis CI build failed

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to integrate Travis CI with my GitHub project. I managed to configure Travis plugin successfully with my repository by following [Travis getting Started Guide](https://travis-ci.org/getting_started)

But when i pushed my first commit after integrating Travis ,it is giving me this error when it auto builds.

```
/home/travis/build.sh: line 179: ./gradlew: Permission denied
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

Below is a screenshot of the Travis build :
[image]

And these are the lines that i have in my **`.travis.yml`** file :

```
language: java
before_script:
 - chmod +x gradlew
```

Comment: Try doing `bash gradlew` or `chmod +x gradlew`.

Comment: I'm running a Windows machine, how am i supposed to write bash commands there ? Also since Travis CI is an online service that auto-builds my project, i don't think that i can supply any commands to it

Answer (score 6):

In your `.travis.yml` add these lines:

```
before_script:
 - chmod +x gradlew
```

Travis instances are linux and require write permissions for executables that output artifacts.

Comment: Nota bene: Git preserves file modes, so you can `chmod +x gradlew` on your local copy and push it.

Comment: Added those lines to the .travis.yml file, but still the build fails. Please see edited question.

Comment: @zulkarnainshah Add `sudo: required` before `before_script`.

Comment: I changed `before_script` to `before_install` and it worked for me.

Comment: I made both the changes suggested by you guys, the old error is gone but a new one has popped up, now build fails giving the following message : **The SDK directory '/home/travis/build/zulkarnainshah/The-Hadith-App/C:\Users\Zulquarnain.Shah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' does not exist.**

Answer (score 3):

I tried that "before_script"-version, but it didn't work for me.

After changing `before_script` to `before_install` it worked as expected (and no sudo was required)

```
before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with this configuration:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7

sudo: required

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew clean build -i --continue
```

And everything is green now.